# Ionic Android Emulator issue

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, emulation

from my app i refer to external API to get data. on browser and built version everything works fine, but on emulator request get rejected. on actual device app works just fine. for debugging i need to test on emulator but i get this error. i checked every article possible but couldn't find solution. here is my configuration

IONIC INFO

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 15.10 
Node Version: v6.3.1
```

CONFIG.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.freemusic372670" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>
        FreeMusic
    </name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
        Your Name Here
    </author>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://10.11.11.127:8100"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://10.11.11.127:8101"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.42.87:8100"/>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.4"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

META HEADER in index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

PLUGINS

```
cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

ERROR

```
{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://databrainz.com/api/search_api.cgi?qry=metallica&format=json&mh=50&where=mpl","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

LOGCAT ERROR

```
11-30 11:51:50.971 3179-3179/com.ionicframework.freemusic372670 D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://10.11.11.127:8100/#/tab/dash: Line 0 : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://databrainz.com/api/search_api.cgi?qry=metallica&format=json&mh=50&where=mpl. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.11.11.127:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) by your webserver. Your Error mentioned this out:

```
…No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.11.11.127:8100' is therefore not allowed access.…
```

Comment: i run with ionic run android -l -c. any ideas how to enable there?

Comment: You must enable it on your webserver configuration (apache or nginx), not on your device.